# Unable to map variable value referencing in JQ for JSON

Tags: json, jq

I am trying to update an environment variable value in my json. Can I do this by making use of a variable as reference?

This works:

```
cat taskdef.json | jq '
  .taskDefinition.containerDefinitions[].environment
  | map(if .name == "ARTIFACT_LOCATION" 
        then . + {"value" : "2"} 
        else . end)'
```

This does not:

```
 cat taskdef.json | jq '
   .taskDefinition.containerDefinitions[].environment
   | map(if .name == "ARTIFACT_LOCATION" 
         then . + {"value" : "**$NEW_ARTIFACTORY_LOCATION**"} 
         else . end)'
```

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines as much as possible.  Also, please clarify what you mean by "I am trying to update an environment variable value".  Your program neither reads nor sets any environment variable.  For reading an environment variable, you could use `env`. See the jq manual.

Comment: @peak My JSON files has a block of code in name value format. I need to update the value field with my variable.

Answer (score 0):

If by `$**$NEW_ARTIFACTORY_LOCATION**` you intend to signify the value of the environment variable $NEW_ARTIFACTORY_LOCATION, then you could use `env.NEW_ARTIFACTORY_LOCATION`, e.g.

```
.taskDefinition.containerDefinitions[].environment
| map(if .name == "ARTIFACT_LOCATION" 
     then . + {"value" : env.NEW_ARTIFACTORY_LOCATION} 
     else . end)'
```

Alternatively, you could use the `--arg NAME VALUE` command-line option.